# How to add picture boxes in rows in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am not sure how to create picture boxes on multiple rows in vb 2010. At the moment, I am only able to create them on
one row and one picture box on the second row. (Eventually I would like to add in 5 rows with 10 pictureboxes on each row) I have used the follow code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 Dim xPosition As Integer = 20
 Dim yPosition As Integer = 40


 For i As Integer = 1 To 20
 Dim pb As New PictureBox

 With pb

 If i < 20 Then
.Name = "PictureBox" & i.ToString
.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
.Size = New Size(60, 60)
.Location = New Point(xPosition, yPosition)
.Image = My.Resources.Seating_No_Person

 Me.Controls.Add(pb)

 AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
 xPosition += 70

 ElseIf i > 10 Then
.Name = "PictureBox" & i.ToString
.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
.Size = New Size(60, 60)
.Location = New Point(20, 120)
.Image = My.Resources.Seating_No_Person

 Me.Controls.Add(pb)
 AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click

 xPosition += 70
 End If

 Dim thisSeating As New Seating

 With thisSeating
.SeatNumber = i
.PB = pb
.Occupied = False
 End With

 seatingList.Add(thisSeating)
 End With
 Next

 End Sub
```

If anyone would be willing to help me or direct me to the correct path, I would be very grateful :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you ever increment your y position?

Comment: In the second row, the new y position is 120, but only one new picturebox appears not 10 in that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim xPosition As Integer = 20
    Dim yPosition As Integer = 40

    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        For j As Integer = 1 To 10
            Dim pb As New PictureBox

            With pb
                .Name = "PictureBox" & i.ToString
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                .Size = New Size(60, 60)
                .Location = New Point(xPosition + (j * 70), yPosition + (i * 100))
                .Image = My.Resources.Seating_No_Person

                Me.Controls.Add(pb)

                AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click

                Dim thisSeating As New Seating

                With thisSeating
                    .SeatNumber = i
                    .PB = pb
                    .Occupied = False
                End With

                seatingList.Add(thisSeating)
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thank you soooooo much :)
I understand now what I had to do - this makes sense